# insert list in multilayer list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a code like:

```
a = ['layer 1', 2, ['layer 2', 22, ['layer 3', 222]]]
```

and I want using `insert` method add the following list `['layer 4', 2222, 3333]` into index 1st of layer 3rd list

what I want is:

```
['layer 1', 2, ['layer 2', 22, ['layer 3', ['layer 4', 2222, 3333], 222]]]
```

Comment: What is your question? Why did you not just do it?

Comment: If you have the layer 1 list, do you know how to get the layer 2 list? And if you have the layer 2 list, do you know how to get the layer 3 list?

Comment: your structure is inconsistent. Do you want the layer4 list to be inserted between 'layer3' and 222 or at the end? inserting in the middle breaks the structure of the other layers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert it into the inner list. The inner list is accessed via index:

```
a = ['layer 1', 2, ['layer 2', 22, ['layer 3', 222]]]
b = ['layer 4', 2222, 3333]
a[2][2].insert(1, b)
```

Comment: Why the assignment to *c* ? c == None

Comment: Ah damn, you're right. Thanks a lot, will fix!

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward indexing leads to this:

```
a = ['layer 1', 2, ['layer 2', 22, ['layer 3', 222]]]
b = ['layer 4', 2222, 3333]
a[-1][-1].insert(1, b)
print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
['layer 1', 2, ['layer 2', 22, ['layer 3', ['layer 4', 2222, 3333], 222]]]
```

Comment: what does [-1][-1] mean in your code?

Comment: @AmirhosseinEnayat  An index of -1 refers to the last item in a list